# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined. Updated React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react so I'm just following youtube video but I got this error and I don't know anything about this. Terminal showing 'Compiled Successfully' but I'm getting this error.
**This is my App.js code**

```
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  React.state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Pay the rent',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Dinner at Pappu',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'CODROBO Meeting',
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  };
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Todos todos={this.state.todos} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and **this is my Todos.js code**

```
function Todos() {
  return this.props.todos.map(todo => <h3> {todo.title} </h3>);
}

export default Todos;
```

*According to video lecture browser must be showing all the todos but I'm getting this error*

Comment: You are creating a functional component and trying to access `this` property, which is the property of class component. so `this.state` will throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you pass props or directly use destructuring.

```
// using props if it's functional component
function Todos(props) {
  return props.todos.map(todo => <h3> {todo.title} </h3>);
}
```

or

```
// using destructuring
   function Todos({todos}) {
    return todos.map(todo => <h3> {todo.title} </h3>);
  }
```

> if it's functional component use `props.todos`. if class based component use `this.props.todos`

As i can see - you need to define **hooks** or class based component to define state

```
// Hooks
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Pay the rent',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Dinner at Pappu',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'CODROBO Meeting',
        completed: false
      }
    ])
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Todos todos={todos} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Class based**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Pay the rent",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Dinner at Pappu",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "CODROBO Meeting",
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.todos.map(todo => (
          <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That would fix one of the issues. But it is not the error he is asking for, but the one that would appear after fixing the problem he asked for. He is asking for state of undefined, which is where ha passes the props, since that also is a functional component, and he is using this.state there.

Comment: When I commented, I did not mean copy-paste my answer into yours.

Comment: @Sodnarts excuse me i didn't see your solution even comments ok.

Comment: using destructing really worked. Thanks @VahidAkhtar

Answer (score 2):

As @Akhil Aravind pointed out you are trying to access `this` in functional component, which is the property of class.
Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Pay the rent',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Dinner at Pappu',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'CODROBO Meeting',
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  };
render(){
return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Todos todos={this.state.todos} />
    </div>
  );
}

}

export default App;

function Todos(props) {
  return props.todos.map(todo => <h3> {todo.title} </h3>);
}

export default Todos;
```

Hope this solves.

Comment: please update the app component also, there are sill issues in the app component. He is trying to access `this.state`, which still throws error

Comment: It will not solve it, and it's not even answering the question he had. He has problems with state of undefined, not props of undefined, look in the first component, there he is passing the props with this.state, and using state like you would in a classic class component, and not through functional components hooks. That is what is giving him the error message he asks for

Comment: did not saw that

Comment: @AkhilAravind I know, I was commenting towards the  post itself, and the question of why it will not solve it, but with a bit more details

Comment: @Rojen this does not qualify as an answer, nowhere is mentioned that todos comes from the props. See answer from Sodnarts

Comment: @Rojen, as Julian said "See answer from Sodnarts" does not mean, copy it and paste it into your own solution. That is stealing someone else's answer. You should rather refer to it, or come up with your own.

Comment: @Sodnarts I did not copy your answer Akhil Aravind pointed out and I fixed it.  Sure you gave better explanation than me.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a functional component, whilst using the syntax of a class component for state. This will not work.

There is two options for fixing this:

First one would be the easiest since most of your code is written with class component syntax -- Change it to a class component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Pay the rent',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Dinner at Pappu',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'CODROBO Meeting',
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  };

   render() {
      return (
         <div className='App'>
             <Todos todos={this.state.todos} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Or you can change the state to the one of a functional component:

**App.js**

```
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Pay the rent',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Dinner at Pappu',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'CODROBO Meeting',
        completed: false
      }
    ])
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Todos todos={todos} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Todos.js**

```
function Todos({todos}) {
  return todos.map(todo => <h3> {todo.title} </h3>);
}

export default Todos;
```

Using these two above files should resolve your issue completely.

Comment: The same error is occurring again.I'm literally very confused. Please explain again.

Comment: Hi, I added the Todos.js, if you use both the component marked as App.js, and Todos.js as stated above it works perfectly, I have tested it

Answer (score 1):

from your program, there seems to be a slight error in the writing state. you can see in my example down below or in [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/hopeful-agnesi-qe3sx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). I hope this helps :)

```js
// App.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Todos from "./Todos";

export default function App() {
  const [todos] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Pay the rent",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Dinner at Pappu",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "CODROBO Meeting",
      completed: false
    }
  ]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Todos todos={todos} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Todos.js
import React from "react";

function Todos({ todos }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {todos.map((item, i) => (
        <div
          style={{
            background: "blue",
            margin: "10px",
            padding: "10px",
            color: "white"
          }}
          key={i}
        >
          <p
            style={{
              background: "red",
              width: "18px",
              borderRadius: "50%",
              padding: "5px"
            }}
          >
            {item.id}
          </p>
          <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Todos;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Todos` function you need to have your `props` from `App` and also since `Todos` is is a functional component, you don't need to use `this` keyword

```js
function Todos(props) {
      return props.todos.map(todo => <h3> {todo.title} </h3>);
    }
    
    export default Todos;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```